# Guitar External sound card with multiple audio devices

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, sound, computer

I want to use my PC as an amp simulator. Im currently using guitar rig 5 with asio4all plugging my guitar trough line in. It works fine but i want to listen to youtube simultaneously but it doesnt work. I tried everything to make it work (multi asio, virtual cable...) but it doesnt. I know that i need an external sound card but im wondering if the really cheap ones (from aliexpress for like 10-20$) will do the trick? I was thinking of buying something like this: https://urlzs.com/6f4TF Im not a pro musician im just playing for fun so the low quality really doesnt bother me that much.

Comment: You need an interface with a dedicated high-impedance guitar input, and preferably from a real instrument manufacturer. If you want it to be cheaper than the Behringer UM-2, buy second-hand.

Comment: I had a similar need and found that a USB audio dongle (I don't recall the make/model, but it was about $20 US 5 or 6 years ago) would work in tandem with the sound card on the motherboard.  That doesn't solve the problem mentioned by Your Uncle Bob, but that would give you more options.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out the "iRig". You can pick up a used/open box on ebay for between $4 and $20 depending on what device you want to connect to. It behaves like any other i/o interface, but pretty minimal. There are some that are exclusively for mobile devices (iOS and android) but I believe there is PC support depending on the model.

Update: I just want to add that I've been using a native instruments Komplete audio 2 with my guitar directly plugged in to the instrument input. I use it with NI Guitar Rig. I also plugged my pedalboard in to it and it sounds great! WAY better than any practice amp I've ever used.